# From windows 8.1 to windows 10 license

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, license, product-key

I bought a laptop with Windows 8.1 pre-installed and activated (I do not have the serial key written down somewhere).

Could I somehow keep the license and install Windows 10 (not upgrading)?

Comment: Windows 8.1 license is stored in the ACPI table.  Why are you not upgrading?  You can perform a clean install from within Windows, and the outcome, is identical to a “clean install” by booting to WinPE

Comment: Either method will require a Windows 10 license by the way

Comment: So, it won't matter that I have windows 8.1 activated?

Comment: Why would it matter?  You are doing a clean install when asked if you want to keep nothing, you are going to select that option.

Comment: I asked if I could somehow keep the license for windows 10 with clean install. But I'm ok even with upgrading the windows if it will keep the license. If that works, problem solved.

Comment: Your Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 license are seperate.  They are not connected in any way.

Comment: Oh, I understand, so it was a silly question after all. Thanks! You can post the answer so I could mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legally... no. However, it is still fully possible to receive a free Windows 10 upgrade. See https://www.howtogeek.com/272201/all-the-ways-you-can-still-get-windows-10-for-free/. The OEM license, however, is for Windows 8.1. Unless Microsoft gives another free upgrade out, what you’re doing is technically wrong. Will they prosecute you? Probably not.
In order to get the key, look for a sticker on the computer. You said you didn’t write it down, but it’s usually on a sticker.
If it’s not on a sticker, this script will retrieve it:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
i = 28
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
x = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
Cur = Cur Mod 24
x = x -1
Loop While x >= 0
i = i -1
KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
i = i -1
KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
End If
Loop While i >= 0
ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

Save it as a .vbs file, and it will open a box with a code you can write down.

Answer (score 1):

Though the offer for free upgrade is theoretically past, [it is still possible to get an upgrade from Windows 8](https://www.howtogeek.com/272201/all-the-ways-you-can-still-get-windows-10-for-free/) at no cost.

If you need the Windows 8.1 product key, there are tools such as [Nirsoft's ProduKey](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to find it. Note that these applications may be viewed as "undesirable software" by some anti-malware suites because they expose information, but they are not malware *per se*... check any software at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload) to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Today I discovered that it is at least possible to install windows 10 on a fresh disk (the laptop previously ran an Acer OEM version of windows 8). It didn't even ask for a product key. The laptop apparently has the windows 8.x key stored inside its firmware. Saved me some effort as I didn't have to install windows 8 first.

So it seems windows 10 does not need a windows 10 license in the case you had a genuine Windows 8.

If the key is not in firmware there are tools to extract it provided your original windows still runs. For this reason and recovery purposes it is nice to buy a separate new disk anyway so you can safely experiment without accidentally deleting your files.

Answer (score -1):

Same here , I installed a fresh **WIndows 10 Home** on top of *Win 8 RTM Professional" OEM key and Windows 10 is activated with Digital License. However the Win10 key is different from the *Win8 RTM Pro OEM* one. PC is HP All-in-one